# How to apply a CSS transition only to the transform property

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions, transition, rotatetransform

I've currently got a `transform: rotate(45deg)` that is applied using a checkbox `:checked` value, and I'm looking for a solution so the CSS transition only applies to the transform value. Right now I've got it setup like so: `transition: all 1s ease`. I don't want it to apply to ***all*** though, just the transform. Right now it's applying the transition to a `color:` change, which I'd like to get rid of.

I feel like this should have been easy to find an answer to, but it's proven to be more difficult than I had imagined. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Here's my **[code pen](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/CEkjz)**. The code in question is **CSS lines 25-28**.

Comment: use `transform` in place of `all` but, to work well for prefixes, it is a bit more annoying. http://bit.ly/1blrJOR

Comment: @Markasoftware I've tried your suggestion, but it just removes the transition entirely.

http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/ByFnj

Comment: @MattBeckham lol, that's because Chrome supports `transition` without prefixes but it needs prefixes for `transform`, and it favors `transition` if it is without prefix. But, your `transition` CSS only counts for `transforms`, not with the `-webkit-` prefix, so...yeah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `transition: transform 1s;`

That is shorthand for:

```
transition-property: transform;
transition-duration: 1s;
```

For prefixes, you need:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
/* etc, for each possibility */
```

Comment: I've made the changes, trying both shorthand and longhand CSS but it removes the transition entirely.

http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/ByFnj

Comment: @MattBeckman - I'm using chrome and your link, with the animation, works fine.

Comment: @MattBeckman I see now, see my update. You have to prefix the actual transform also. There's a lot to it if you need to support the prefixes :(

Comment: @m59 I'm using Safari, but I just tried that code pen in Chrome, and it does the same thing. It will rotate, but it does so instantly, it's not applying the '1s ease'.

Comment: @MattBeckman working perfectly for me in Chrome (I just used the chrome prefix here) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LfiFu

Comment: Ya I made the changes before you edited your post with the browser prefixes. That solves it :)

Comment: Here's the final code I ended up using.

`transition: transform 1s ease;
-o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;`